# Bash splitting a large gzipped file

Tags: bash, awk, split

I've been recently dealing with some file processing, and I am trying to write a bash one-liner, which would look something like:

```
zcat largefile.gz | split_by_delimiter_into_separate_files
```

Things I tried:

```
zcat largefile.gz | awk '{print $0 " //"> "separate_file" NR}' RS='//'
```

The delimiter I am trying to split upon is "//". I know something like python could probably solve this into a couple of lines, yet my project is not python-based and this is thus not an option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
zcat largefile.gz | awk -vRS='//' '{print $0 " //"> "separate_file" NR}'
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Why exactly this works?

Comment: You wrong setting variable. I use command line flag `-v` to set up it. Or you can do like this: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="//"} {print $0 " //"> "separate_file" NR}'`. Block `BEGIN{}` will be runned once at start of script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` which I believe does exactly what you need:

```
zcat largefile.gz | split -p '//' - separate_file_
```

will create files prefixed with `separate_file_` with the content of `large file`, split on `//`